# c++ big data member only used in testing

Tags: c++, templates

I have a big data member for a class, which is only used for testing:

```
template <bool testing>
class foo {
  int testbuf[1000];
}
```

How can I make it so? Only when `testing` is `true`, include `testbuf[]`?

Answer (score 3):

Specialize:

```
template <bool> class foo { };

template <> class foo<true>
{
    // everything needed for testing
};
```

---

**Update:** To clarify some points raised in the comments: You would write one such "testing" template per individual *item* that you want to specialize, so that there's no code duplication. Imagine your real class template is actually `bar`:

```
template <bool Testing>
class bar
: private foo<Testing>          // specializable base
{
    // common stuff

    Widget<Testing> widget;     // specializable member

    Gadget          gadget;     // unconditional member
};
```

You can also use composition rather than inheritance; whichever fits best. If you go with inheritance, make sure to spell out `this->testbuf`.

Comment: This is the c++-iest way, I think.

Comment: That works well for an otherwise empty class, but once the class starts having something real to do you have two separate versions to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, in this case I only put the implementation in the first one, and no need to duplicate code in the second one except the testing part, right?

Comment: @PeteBecker: It should be clear that this is just a model. If your class is complex, you would package the testing parts into separate, smaller templates and include those into your main class. You can think of the approach as "testing traits", if you prefer.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: You can say `template <bool Testing> class real_class : private foo<Testing> { /* ... */ };`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ifdef stuff

```
#define DEBUG_MODE

class Foo{
  #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
      int testbuf[1000];
  #else
      int testbuf[10];
  #endif
}
```

Comment: so that way, during debug it gets compiled, else in release, it gets stripped and wont even be in the source

Comment: That depends on whether your compiler sets `DEBUG_MODE` in debug and unsets it in release mode. Otherwise set via build defines.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <bool testing>
class foo {
}
```

and

```
template <>
class foo <true>{
  int testbuf[1000];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `testing` isn't just used to hold that buff.

```
template <bool testing>
struct foobuf
{};
template <>
struct foobuf<true>
{
  enum {testbuf_size = 1000};
  int testbuf[testbuf_size];
  foobuf() { std::fill_n( &testbuff[0], testbuf_size, int() ); }
};

template <bool testing>
class foo : public foobuf<testing> {
  // ...
};
```

Going a bit further, you could include a dotest function in foobuf that works like this:

```
template<bool>
struct foobuf
{
  template<typename Func>
  void doTest( Func const& unused );
};
template<>
struct foobuf<true>
{
  enum {testbuf_size = 1000};
  int testbuf[testbuf_size];
  foobuf() { std::fill_n( &testbuf[0], testbuf_size, int() ); }
  template<typename Func>
  void doTest( Func const& f )
  {
    f( testbuf, testbuf_size );
  }
};
```

which you would use like this within foo:

```
void foo::some_function(...)
{
  // some code
  doTest( [&]( int* buf, size_t length )
  {
    // the code in here only runs if we test was true in foo
    // and if so, it has access to the test buff via the buf* parameter
    // oh, and it will be almost certainly inlined if test was true in foo
    // and thrown away and never created if it was false.
  });
}
```

but that is just me.

Comment: What's the use of the `enum`?

Comment: Generally bare constants should be avoided.  The enum let's me name that value.